# HTTP Error in my POST data

Tags: php, javascript, post

This question is a continuation to this previous [question of mine in here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839930/http-error-on-adding-large-data-using-jquery-ajax)

I have this `HTTP: Error` in my previous code due to query strings that is more than the limit to be send in the url to my webservice (that was what I understand). I was using method `Get` before and I was told by **kleinohad** to use method `POST`. Now, I am using `POST` but still have an error like the one I have in method `GET`, which is the 'HTTP: Error' everytime I have lots of `post data` to be send to the url, (it will not get through my webservice.).

Here is my javascript code:

```
var dataJSON = {
    "SessionID": $.cookie("SessionID"),
    "operation": "add",       
    "transaction_date":$('#tallyDate').val(),
    "supplier_id":$('#supplierInput').attr("name"),
    "wood_specie_id":$('#woodSpecie').attr("name"),   
    "lines":plank_data,
    "scaled_by":$('#tallyScaled').val().toUpperCase(),
    "tallied_by":$('#tallyTallied').val().toUpperCase(),
    "checked_by":$('#tallyChecked').val().toUpperCase(),
    "total_bdft":$('#tallyTotal').val(),
    "final":"N"
  }; 
  alert('this is the datajson from add :   '  + JSON.stringify(dataJSON));

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: dataJSON,
    url: 'processjson2.php?' + $.param({path:'update/tallyHdr',json:JSON.stringify(dataJSON)}),
    dataType: primeSettings.ajaxDataType,
    success: function(data) {
      if ('error' in data)
      {
        showMessage('ERROR: ' + data["error"]["msg"]);
      }
      else{
        $('#tblTallyHdr').trigger('reloadGrid'); 
      }
    }
  });
```

And here is my .php code (thanks to SMka):

```
<?php

//this is already running code but could not accept large query string
 $data_url = http_build_query (array('json' => $_REQUEST["json"]));
$data_len = strlen ($data_url); 

echo file_get_contents("http://localhost:8001/" . $_REQUEST["path"], false, stream_context_create(
    array (
        'http' => array(
            'method'=>'POST',
            'header' => "Connection: close\r\nContent-Length: $data_len\r\n",
            'content'=>$data_url
        )
    )
));
?>
```

My question is, why I can't still send many data using `post` to my webservice? I was really thinking that using `post` method can help me out in sending many request to my webservice, so what's the problem with my code?

**EDIT**   I change my code into this

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataJSON,
        url: 'processjson2.php?',
        dataType: primeSettings.ajaxDataType,
        success: function(data) {}
})
```

and my output url is this `http://localhost/jQueryStudy/RamagalHTML/processjson2.php?path=update/tallyHdr`, which give me an error `Session ID not found`. I found out that my datajson was not sent to my url webservice datajson was not there.

Comment: Hi jayAnn,
Please use firebug like addons to verify the 'posted' data.

Comment: There's no problem really with my post data in firebug, I can see them. I can send them to my webservice and it function well but only in small query. But everytime I have many data to send, I will get error

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line of code:

```
url: 'processjson2.php?' + $.param({path:'update/tallyHdr',json:JSON.stringify(dataJSON)}),
```

This line appends data to the URL to which you are posting your request.  If you have too much data, the URL will overwhelm the web server.  (Basically, you are still performing a GET request.)

Instead, replace that line with the following.

```
url: 'processjson2.php',
```

Then add `path:'update/tallyHdr'` to your dataJSON object, and see if that works.

Comment: I already test it now and it made my url into this `http://localhost/jQueryStudy/RamagalHTML/processjson2.php?json={"path":"update%2FtallyHdr","SessionID"......`, instead of this `http://localhost/jQueryStudy/RamagalHTML/processjson2.php?path=update/tallyHdr&json={"SessionID"....`. And the result is all the same.. OK in small data, error in large data.

Comment: Can you please provide the code for your updated `$.ajax()` request?

Comment: You updated the code I was asking for.

I am confused now.  The error you are getting, `if ('error' in data)` is from your old code's `$.ajax()` request.  If the code segment `if ('error' in data)` still exists, replace it with `if (data['error'])`.

Comment: i just copy my code by what you said in your answer. Replaced my url line with this `url: 'processjson2.php',  `. I dont change any from my original question. I just add my new code from your answer. And I get that error.

Comment: Can you please use Firebug to determine what response you are getting to the request?  The error you are getting means that `data` is not an associative array.

Comment: i change my code with your `if (data['error'])` and it give me this new error `data is null
[Break On This Error] if (data['error']) `. I guess it is because there is no really data being sent because my data json was not send to my url

Comment: Did you add `path:'update/tallyHdr'` to `jsonData`?  If you could make sure all of your code is updated in your question, that would be helpful.

Comment: Please see my edit. I just put my path in my original question. Please also update your answer. Should i change my .php also? since it cant send postdata to my url? It can get my `path` in my `datajson`, but not the rest of the data to be send.

Answer (score 0):

I have now my answer. Cheeken is **correct** when she/he said that this line:

```
url: 'processjson2.php?' + $.param({path:'update/tallyHdr',json:JSON.stringify(dataJSON)}),
```

is the problem and that I am performing a `get` request. And that I should replace it with this:

```
url: 'processjson2.php?',
```

So, where should I put my dataJSON?
Here's my running code that I used:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: $.param({json:(JSON.stringify(dataJSON))}),
    url: 'processjson2.php?path=update/tallyHdr',
    dataType: primeSettings.ajaxDataType,
    success: function(data) {
      if ('error' in data)
      {
        showMessage('ERROR: ' + data["error"]["msg"]);
      }
      else{
        $('#tblTallyHdr').trigger('reloadGrid'); 
      }
    }
  });
```

This line `$.param({json:(JSON.stringify(dataJSON))})` converts my **dataJSON** into a query string, while **json** is the variable that holds my json data. That's all that change I nade to run my program code with ajax